# Performing operations on heroku ENV vars in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to test for equality against a heroku ENV var, to no avail.

Example:

```
if a['answer']['question_id'] == ENV['HEROKU_VAR']
  # this expression was supposed to be true!
end
```

I've sent each side of the expression to the debugger and they print the same value.

My only presumption is that the ENV var is an object that can't have operations performed on it.

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Print them with `inspect`, that might reveal something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, even if you declare your Heroku var as an int, e.g. HEROKU_VAR=12345, when you call it from anywhere in your app, it seems it throws back a string, which you need to convert back to an integer.
I solved this problem as follows:

```
if a['answer']['question_id'] == ENV['HEROKU_VAR'].to_i
  # this expression was supposed to be true and it IS!
end
```

Comment: environment-variables get passed to your execution environment and will always be strings. if you want to make an integer out of it, use ```to_i```